# How to compress all files in the current directory using lz4 using GNU parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel, lz4

How to compress all files in the current directory using lz4 using GNU parallel?

I try `ls | parallel lz4` but it outputs to `stdout`. Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-m` option for multiple input files (implies automatic output filenames).

```
ls | parallel lz4 -m
```

Comment: 1) Is there any difference between `ls | parallel lz4 -m` and `parallel lz4 -m ::: *`? 2) I don't understand: why there is a need of `-m` if lz4 is called N times in parallel, each time with a single file name? What do I miss?

Comment: 1) Yes, they're equivalent. 2) I'm not entirely certain but I don't think parallel is necessarily running one file at a time.

Comment: 2) Both gzip (for example) and lz4 can take a single argument "input file". Then why `ls | parallel gzip` works (as expected), while `ls | parallel lz4` doesn't? Can you guess / explain?

Answer (score 0):

> but it outputs to `stdout`. Why? How to fix?

The answers are in the man page...
Why it outputs to `stdout`:

```
  •   When  no  destination is specified, result is sent on implicit output, which depends on stdout status. When stdout is Not the
       console, it becomes the implicit output. Otherwise, if stdout is the console, the implicit output is filename.lz4.
```

In this particular case (`parallel` runs `lz4`) the `stdout` is not the console (see *steeldriver*'s answer [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322542)); also, if you check your output it contains warning(s):

```
Warning : using stdout as default output. Do not rely on this behavior: use explicit `-c` instead !
```

How to fix (next paragraph in the man page):

```
   •   It is considered bad practice to rely on implicit output in scripts. because the script's environment may change. Always  use
       explicit  output in scripts. -c ensures that output will be stdout. Conversely, providing a destination name, or using -m en‐
       sures that the output will be either the specified name, or filename.lz4 respectively.
```

So the proper way would be to either provide a destination name

```
parallel lz4 {} {}.lz4 ::: ./*
```

or use the `-m` switch (same result but no verbosity):

```
parallel lz4 -m ::: ./*
```